# Can't search any data from the hive partition table via OCI HDFS connector to Object Storage

Tags: hdfs

I tried to create the Hive external table to OCI Object storage but can't search any data from the hive partition table. There is no output from the query
`select * from table_name limit 10;` It is an issue only with the hive partition table. For a normal non-partition table, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the documentation here [Using the HDFS Connector with Spark](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/hdfsconnectorspark.htm) to understand the pre-requisites. In addition to this, the way to load data into partitioned tables is different from the normal non-partitioned table. There is little manual work of mentioning the partition data which can be done by executing the following query

> LOAD DATA INPATH {location} INTO TABLE {partitioned_table} PARTITION
> {name=value}

To understand it better, let’s consider the example of movies.csv file uploaded in the Object Storage bucket from the above documentation.
(You can perform steps similar to the ones described below to resolve the issue)

Step 1: Create hive external table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE movie_table(
movieId integer, title string, genres string)
partitioned by (pa_month string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'oci://bucket_name@namespace_name/moviepartition';
```

Step 2: Load data from the file placed in Object Storage bucket to the partitioned table

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'oci://bucket_name@namespace_name/movicepartition' INTO TABLE movie_table PARTITION {pa_month=202104};
```

Step 3: Perform SELECT query to view the contents in the table

```
select * from table_name limit 10;
```

Syntax to view tables and partitions

```
show tables;
show paritions table_name;
```